# How to extract the text between many commas in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a problem to extract the suburb from a address.
For example, the dress is "143 Stephanie St, Upper Kedron, QLD, 4055."
How to set up a formula to extract the buburb, Upper Kedron, from the address?

I really appreciate your review :)

Comment: Is what you require to extract always between the first and second commas?

Comment: You could use text to columns to separate out everything and put back together what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract second word separated by comma:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",255)),255,255))
```

You will have problem if Upper Kedron is not 2nd word like for example:
143, Stephanie St, Upper Kedron, QLD, 4055 (this will extract Stephanie St).

So if you have cases that formula doesn't work give us more inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As per the previous answer, looks like your suburb can be in any position. So the best way is to split the address to multiple columns and then choose a column of your suburb.

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),1+((COLUMN(A1)-1)*999),999))`

[image]